# How to singularize route path part using FOSRestBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.8

I have this controller (a snippet here)

```
/**
 * Class UserController
 * @package Belka\AuthBundle\Controller
 */
class UserController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @View()
     *
     * @Route(requirements={"user"="\w+"})
     * @ParamConverter("user", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     */
    public function postGlobaltokenAction(User $user)
    {
        ...
    }
```

that automatically generates the route:

```
  post_user_globaltoken      POST     ANY      ANY    /api/users/{user}/globaltokens.{_format}
```

which is OK, except for the fact I would like "globaltoken" singularized. Is that possible? I cannot find any annotation to tweak this. Should I hardcode the route in my `route.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found two ways:

**Using a personal `Inflector`**

as [Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/1.7/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#changing-pluralization-in-generated-routes) suggests, you can register a personal `Inflector` which returns "globaltoken" always as singular, whereas all the other resources will be pluralized:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Util\Inflector;
use FOS\RestBundle\Util\Inflector\DoctrineInflector;
use FOS\RestBundle\Util\Inflector\InflectorInterface;

/**
 * Inflector class
 *
 */
class NoopInflector extends DoctrineInflector implements InflectorInterface
{
    public function pluralize($word)
    {
        if($word == "globaltoken")
            return $word;

        return parent::pluralize($word);
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    belka.auth_bundle.util.inflector:
      class: Belka\AuthBundle\Util\NoopInflector
```

but I found this way a bit dirty, as I could need the plural form in the future.

**Overriding the `FOSRestBundle` auto-generated routes**

It's that simple! Just add the `@Route` annotation on the right methos and you're done!

```
/**
 * @View()
 *
 * @Route("/users/{user}/globaltoken", defaults={"_format" = "json"}, requirements={"user"="\w+"})
 *
 * @ParamConverter("user", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 */
public function postAction(User $user)
{
}
```

Now if I call `php app/console debug:route` I get what I want:

```
post_user_globaltoken      POST     ANY      ANY    /api/users/{user}/globaltoken.{_format}
```